# Test Class unrecognized in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

I have this class, but eclipse does not recognize it as a test class, so I can not run it as a Junit test, I am using TestNG is a testing framework inspired from JUnit and NUnit but introducing some new functionalities that make it more powerful and easier to use,

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class ApplicationServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    ApplicationDao dao;

    @InjectMocks
    ApplicationMutatorServiceImpl applicationMutatorServiceImpl;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {

        Application application = new Application();
        applicationMutatorServiceImpl.save(application);
        System.out.println (application);

    }
}
```

in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a tearDown() in your class?

Comment: `JUnit != TestNG` How could you possibly think that Eclipse recognizes your _TestNG_ test classes as _JUnit_ test classes? Well ... I am not familiar with TestNG, but maybe the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) help.

Comment: You mean that 'Eclipse does not recognize it as a JUnit test class'? This is likely the proper description of the problem. Have you checked whether your testing framework is supported by default in eclipse? If not, use JUnit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have TestNG plugin installed.
http://singinginthesunlight.blogspot.in/2016/02/testng-for-dummies.html

Otherwise you can run it through Maven